# How implicit varchar to numeric works till 999 and does not work after that

Tags: sql-server-2005

The below sql works:

```
DECLARE @VAL1 VARCHAR(50), @VAL2 INT
SET @VAL1 = '999'
SET @VAL2 = 6414
SELECT ROUND(CAST(((@VAL1 * 100.00)/@VAL2) AS FLOAT), 2)
```

Where as this one fails with 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.'

```
DECLARE @VAL1 VARCHAR(50), @VAL2 INT
SET @VAL1 = '1000'
SET @VAL2 = 6414
SELECT ROUND(CAST(((@VAL1 * 100.00)/@VAL2) AS FLOAT), 2)
```

The only difference between the two is that in the second one @VAL1 value is 1000 instead of 999.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implicitly converting the string into a number by multtiplying it with a number. The type of the number that you are multiplying with determines the type that the string is converted to. The database uses the smallest `numeric` type that can hold the number `100.00` which is `numeric(5,2)`, so that's what the string is converted to too.

If you explicitly convert the string to a number, you can choose a type that can handle the range that you need.

If you for example convert it to an `int` it can handle values up to `'2147483647'`:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(((CAST(@VAL1 AS INT) * 100.00)/@VAL2) AS FLOAT), 2)
```